# OpenCV Mat image changes size after function call by reference

Tags: opencv

i am writing an application using OpenCV. Recently i've noticed strange things sometimes happen to cv::Mat object when passed to function by reference. Here's the code:

```
cv::Mat img1=cv::imread(argv[1]);
cv::Mat img2=cv::imread(argv[2]);

double scale=0.4;
int thr=52; 

//resize image
cv::Mat tmp;
img1.copyTo(tmp);
cv::resize(tmp,img1,cv::Size(),scale,scale);
img2.copyTo(tmp);
cv::resize(tmp,img2,cv::Size(),scale,scale);

cv::Mat im1,im2;

try
{
    cv::Sobel(img1,im1,CV_8U , 0/*x order*/, 1/*y order*/,5/*kernel size*/,1/*scale*/);
    cv::Sobel(img2,im2,CV_8U , 0/*x order*/, 1/*y order*/,5/*kernel size*/,1/*scale*/);
}
catch(...)
{
    std::cout << "Something went wrong calculating Sobel!" << std::endl;
}

cv::imshow("im1",im1);
cv::imshow("im2",im2);

//create empty mat with the same size as im1, im2
cv::Mat bin1(im1.size().height, im1.size().width, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat bin2(im2.size().height, im2.size().width, CV_8UC1);


std::cout << "_________OUT_________" << std::endl;
std::cout << im1.size().width << " " << bin1.size().height << std::endl;
std::cout << im2.size().width << " " << bin2.size().height << std::endl;


getExtreme(im1,bin1,thr);
getExtreme(im2,bin2,thr);
```

The getExtreme function is defined like this:

```
 void getExtreme(cv::Mat &img, cv::Mat &dst,int prag)
 {

    int x=img.size().width;
int y=img.size().height;
    std::cout << "_________________IN______________________" << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << " " << dst.size().width << std::endl;
    std::cout << y << " " << dst.size().height << std::endl;



    int i,j;

for (i=0;i<x;i++)
{ 
            for (j=0;j<y;j++)
    {
                    if(img.data[img.channels()*img.cols*j+i]>prag)
                    dst.data[dst.channels()*dst.cols*j+i]=255; 
    }
}
 }
```

while the images which size i am printing are the same, the output of the program is:

__*OUT****_*_**
819 819
819 819
***_*__*_*____***IN****_*__*_*__*_*___**
819 819
435 435
**__*_*__*_*_***IN****_*__*_*__*_*____**
819 819
435 435

so for some reason the bin1 and bin2 images (cv::Mat) change size. however, if i set the double scale=0.4; to double scale=1;, thus not resizing the image but retaining its original size, the size of the image matches outside and inside the function:

__*OUT****_*_**
2048 1088
2048 1088
***_*__*_*____***IN****_*__*_*__*_*___**
2048 2048
1088 1088
**__*_*__*_*_***IN****_*__*_*__*_*____**
2048 2048
1088 1088

What am i doing wrong? How does resizing influence the mat objects? why is it different at all, if it is passed by reference i should have the same object inside the function.

thanks

Comment: By the way with your raw data access to pixel, if the image have more than 1 channel, you set only the first channel to 255 in your loop. Consider using OpenCV thresholding functions as shown in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Passing image as reference to a function should not change their size! Quick look at your code, I dont see any particular error but there might be some memory access in another part of your program that corrupt your data but does not make the program crash. You should check your program with a profiler.

Another advice, nevertheless, your function getExtreme seems to perform a simple thresholding operation. This can be achieved in OpenCV either using [`cv::threshold`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=threshold#cv.Threshold) or using `operator>` in the cv::Mat (see [Matrix expressions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat#matrix-expressions)). Example:

```
cv::threshold(im1,bin1,thr, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
cv::threshold(im2,bin2,thr, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

or

```
bin1 = im1 > thr;
bin2 = im2 > thr;
```